# Como posso deixar o CardView com tamanho dinâmico?

Tags: java, android

Eu estou com um probleminha...

Tenho vários CardsView e o tamanho deles está estático eu gostaria de saber como posso deixar esse tamanho adaptavel ao que tem no cardView.

Porque em um CardView eu tenho uma lista que vem dados do banco e se o tamanho estiver estático vai acabar não aparecendo todos os registros.

Como posso fazer para tornar esse CardView adaptável ao tamanho da listView?

Segue um trecho do meu código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hide_layout"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/id_ocorrecia"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="5"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <TextView
                                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                    android:textSize="15dp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                    android:text="Ocorrências"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:id="@+id/txtEquipe"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:background="#A9A9A9"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                >
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:padding="10dp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                                    android:background="#A9A9A9"
                                    ></LinearLayout>

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_weight="8"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                        <TextView
                                            android:textStyle="bold"
                                            android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                            android:textSize="12dp"
                                            android:padding="8dp"
                                            android:text="SERVIÇO"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:ems="10"
                                            android:id="@+id/ff"
                                            />

                                    </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_weight="4"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                                    <TextView
                                        android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                        android:textSize="12dp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:padding="8dp"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:ems="10"
                                        android:text="TOTAL"
                                        android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
                                        />
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_weight="4"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                        android:textSize="12dp"
                                        android:text="EM ATEND."
                                        android:padding="8dp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:ems="10"
                                        android:id="@+id/txtRecursos"
                                        />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>



                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ListView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/lstOcorrencias"
                                android:divider="@null"
                                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                                />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/visivel"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                ></LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="8"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <TextView
                                    android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                    android:textSize="12dp"
                                    android:text="Outros (Demais Serviços)"
                                    android:padding="10dp"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:id="@+id/txtOut"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_weight="4"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                                <TextView
                                    android:padding="10dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                    android:textSize="12dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:id="@+id/txtoutTotal"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_weight="4"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                                <TextView
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                    android:textSize="12dp"
                                    android:padding="10dp"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:id="@+id/txtoutEmAtendimento"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:background="#A9A9A9"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                android:background="#A9A9A9"
                                >

                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="8"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <TextView
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                    android:textSize="12dp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:padding="8dp"
                                    android:text="TOTAL GERAL"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:id="@+id/txtTotalGeral"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_weight="4"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                                <TextView
                                    android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                    android:textSize="12dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:padding="8dp"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:text="0"
                                    android:id="@+id/txtTotalQTD"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_weight="4"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                                <TextView
                                    android:textColor="@color/preto"
                                    android:textSize="12dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:padding="8dp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:text="0"
                                    android:id="@+id/txtTotalGEmAtendimentoQTD"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Removi a reposta, realmente eu não tinha reparado naquela sua ultima frase lá. Estou sem tempo de ver agora, mais tarde se ninguém colocar uma resposta eu tento elaborar uma reposta para ti. =p

Comment: A verdade é que eu tenho um ScrollView e dentro uma listView no caso o cardView está dinâmico pq eu coloquei como wrap-content como o Ack falou. Agora o problema é que do jeito como está só é exibido o primeiro registro da lista....o restante é cortado...

Comment: mas....mas Ack não se vá. =(

Comment: Realmente esse layout está complicado, além disso, usar `ListView` dentro de um `ScrollView` não é recomendado. Vai dar um bom trabalho, mas minha recomendação é usar o `RecyclerView` com um Header e um Footer para englobar todo o restante do layout que está fixo acima e baixo do `ListView`.

Comment: Sim a solução foi utilizar RecycleView mesmo tudo certo! Funcionou!